# emberjs, how to bind method from controller to service?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, service, bind

I have big emberjs application and I need to start using ember service a little bit more.
so I have a method in my controller that I want it to be available as a service in all the modals, and components where I inject the service.

but its not working, and with no error... si is this a good way to do this? why its not wotking?

so my method in the controller is:

```
openModalPrices () {
        //method in controller
    },
```

the service has another method:

```
openModalPricesFromService () {
        //method in service
    },
```

and in my INIT in the Controller I am binding like this:

```
init: function() {
   this._super(...arguments);
   this.get('priceService').openModalPricesFromService(this.openModalPrices.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: Whats is your ember version? What do you mean by "not working"; what exactly do you expect to happen, what happens, and why do you think this is wrong? Generally you dont make a method on a Controller avaliable everywhere, use a service *instead*. So move the function to the service.

Comment: The problem will be that methods on a controller should not be invoked when not on a controller's route. But a service is global and methods on it can be called from anywhere, anytime. The real question is, why do you want to keep the method in the controller but call it from a service? What's the real problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

instead of initing from the controller (which is a singleton, so lifecycle / creation isn't what you'd natively expect), can you use the `afterModel` hook of the route?

in 2022, I personally have 0 use for controllers, even for query params.

To call your service method from a route, I would do this:

```
export default class MyRoute extends Route {
  @service myService;

  afterModel() {
    this.myService.openModalPricesFromService();
  }
}
```

Also, there should be no need to use `bind` in emberjs -- if you want to work through options on that, feel free to open another StackOverflow question <3